# Porque no funciona mi código Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quiero que al presionar el boton cambie este su color y también el  body y el  div, pero solo cambia el body los otros dos(div,button) se mantienen con el mismo color. No se que puede estar mal en el código javascript.

```js
function cambiarColor(){
  document.body.style.background = "blue";
  document.div.style.background = "yellow";
  document.button.style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
 body{background-color: yellow;}
 div{background-color: red; height: 50px;}
 button{color: white; background-color:blue;padding: 4px; }
```

```html
 <button type="button"  onclick="cambiarColor()">Colorear</button>
```

Comment: Hola, te aconsejo que en tu pregunta hables sobre que elemento de tu código parece generarte el problema, no pongas preguntas tan amplias y ambiguas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estas accediendo a los objetos por su `id` o por su `clase`.

```js
  function cambiarColor() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
    document.body.style.background = "blue";
    myDiv.style.background = "green";
    myButton.style.background = "red";
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div> 
<button type="button" id="myButton" onclick="cambiarColor()">Colorear</button>
```

Comment: Entonces quiere decir que el unic0 elemento al que puedo acceder de esa forma es el body y los otros siempre tengo que acceder por su id?

Comment: si siempre pór su ID

Comment: Antes de dar por respondido mi pregunta, crees que es una buena manera de aplicar este código para cambiar los colores de una pagina, por ejemplo tengo pensado hacer una pagina que al presionar un botón cambie todo sus colores de sus elementos en la interfaz  a colores para personas con daltonismo?

Comment: Para una persona normal los colores fuertes no motivan a seguir usando la pagina... con lo del daltonismo no te podria decir amigo

Comment: no, los colores que he elegido son  de ejemplo,lo preguntaba por si es que era optimo  implementar de esta forma el código para cambiar los colores de una pagina . de todas formas gracias me ayudo tu solución.

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que solo agregues clases al `body` o a una etiqueta padre principal y desde allí cambias los colores a los elementos que quieres por `css`

Comment: Si tienes una pagina de mas de un solo archivo, te recomendaria que guardes una variable en una base de datos diciendo si quiere el color comun o otros colores, ejemplo base de datos "pagina", columna "tema" podria ser 1=colores comunes, 2=colores para daltonicos, entonces haces un query a la base de datos y que php compare tema y a partir de ahi haces un codigo:`if(tema == '1'){ echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilocomun.css"/>'; } else { echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilodaltonicos.css"/>'; }` si quieres que te haga un ejemplo mas extenso, pidemelo y hago una respiesta :)

Comment: Si seria buena idea con una base de datos.. gracias Patrick, lo tomare encuenta